# What does my exported cmake static library require private links?

Tags: cmake, static-linking

I am trying to `find_package(foo)`, then link to it:

```
find_package(foo)
add_executable(bar ...)
target_link_libraries(bar PRIVATE fooStatic)
```

but when I try to build, I get:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:58 (add_library):
  Target "bar" links to target "gpgme::gpgme" but the target was
  not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
```

---

`foo` itself is another project which has been installed.  `foo/CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
find_package(gpgme)

add_library(fooObjects OBJECT ...)
add_library(foo        SHARED $<TARGET_OBJECTS:fooObjects>)
add_library(fooStatic  STATIC $<TARGET_OBJECTS:fooObjects>)

target_link_libraries(foo       PUBLIC fooObjects PRIVATE gpgme::gpgme)
target_link_libraries(fooStatic PUBLIC fooObjects PRIVATE gpgme::gpgme)

...
install(TARGETS foo fooStatic fooObjects EXPORT fooTargets ...)
export(EXPORT fooTargets FILE fooTargets.cmake)
configure_package_config_file(fooConfig.cmake.in fooConfig.cmake ...)
...
```

The generated `fooTargets.cmake` (included by `fooConfig.cmake`) contains:

```
add_library(foo SHARED IMPORTED)                                               
                                                                                
set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES                                           
  INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "fooObjects"
)                                                                               
                                                                                
add_library(slibStatic STATIC IMPORTED)                                         
                                                                                
set_target_properties(fooStatic PROPERTIES                                     
  INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "fooObjects;\$<LINK_ONLY:gpgme::gpgme>"
)
```

Why is `gpgme::gpgme` listed as an `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` for the static version of the library?  Is there a way to avoid this?  I tried linking `foo` to a gpgme static target, but that didn't change the problem.

I know I could add `find_dependency(gpgme)` to my `fooConfig.cmake.in`, but it would be nice if my users didn't have to install `libgpgme-dev` to link against my project.

Comment: "Why is `gpgme::gpgme` listed as an `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` for the static version of the library?" - Creation of a **static** library does NOT involve **linking** step. So the file `fooStatic.a` contains neither codes from `gpgme::gpgme` library no information about linking with it. When you use `target_link_libraries` for a static library, CMake understand that as a requirement to perform such linkage for the **consumer** of that library. In your case the library can be consumed via the EXPORT file, this is why the linkage become part of that file.

Comment: Succinctly: it's listed there because your static library truly does depend on it. Why do you think this would not be so?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I had forgotten that the static library does not involve a linking step.  This makes sense.Thanks

Comment: @AlexReinking Your target depends on things in `LINK_LIBRARIES`, not `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES`. `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` is for anyone downstream who links to your target and that's what I was trying to simplify.

Comment: @Stewart - you're not understanding `$<LINK_ONLY:...>`, then.

Comment: @AlexReinking Ah, seems there's still lots I don't understand.  Thanks for pointing me in that direction.